# Is there a good example passing build parameters with Python jenkinsapi and why is the below example failing?

Tags: python, jenkins

I'm trying to invoke a job using the Python jenkinsapi package. I am able to kick of the build using jop.py no problem, but when trying to pass string parameters to the Jenkins server the parameters are not being picked up and the default values configured on the Jenkins server are being used instead.

Here's a quick example of what I'm using using job.py invoke:

```
my_job.invoke(securitytoken = 'mytoken', params = {'param1':'value1', 'param2':
'value2'})
```

Again, the above kicks off the build successfully on the Jenkins server, but none of the parameter values are picked up by the Job on the server and instead the default values in the Job config on the server are used instead.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with the above usage? Are there other parameters that are needed? Does someone have an example of invoking parameterized builds using jenkinsapi?

This is for jenkinsapi 0.1.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into this one a bit more, it turns out the URL was not getting constructed properly. By changing line 91 in jenkinsbase.py in version 0.1.16 using Python 2.6.4 I was finally able to get the build parameters to pass properly:

- if params: stream = fn_urlopen( url, urllib.urlencode(params) )
- if params: stream = fn_urlopen( url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params) )

After changing this line in jenkinsbase.py, the example in my original question had the build parameters passed into the job correctly.